# Using .htaccess RewriteRule to catch requests and rewrite them to another domain in the same server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 domains, lets use these as examples:

- business.com
- mystore.com

Currently, the **business.com** domain loads the store pages using this structure.

- business.com/mystore
- business.com/mystore/search
- business.com/mystore/catalogue

In this case, those are the urls for a store called **mystore**. Since there can be any amount of stores inside the **business.com** domain, this is the current `.htaccess` rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/?$ store/index.php?store=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/buscar$ store/search.php?store=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{2,50})/catalogo/?$ store/catalogue.php?store=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That works great for basic profiles; but now I need to activate a premium kind of profile, where the stores can use their own domain, so that this should be the new structure for that particular store:

- mystore.com/
- mystore.com/search
- mystore.com/catalogue

Both domains are in the same managed apache server. Is there a way via the `.htaccess` file from **mystore.com**, where I could actually catch any requests and then actually request the value from **business.com/mystore/*** ? So, for example:

> mystore.com/catalogue/nice-product/384

actually retrieves the result from

> business.com/mystore/catalogue/nice-product/384

Just for clarification, the actual path of each domain root in the server, is:

```
/www/business/html
/www/mystore/html
```

All ideas welcomed, thanks!

Comment: Why are these domains pointing to different folders in the first place? Do you need to serve any _additional_ content on those custom domains, that is not covered by the main version of the shop already? Usually, one would rather set up an alias domain here, that points to the exact same web root folder to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe the only purpose of this, is that the store can handle their own domain, so that instead of going to business.com/store/catalogue, they can share their very own mystore.com/catalogue

Comment: Then I would set them up as alias domains, instead of having them point to a different directory. A RewriteCond checking on the host name can then be used to determined what further rewriting has to happen.